# Уникальное значение логина

Tags: mysql, java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

Есть форма регистрации, которая добавляет в БД пользователей. Столкнулся с проблемой что при регистрации пользователя с существующим ключом - он перезаписывает всего- лишь старое значение, вместо того чтобы вернуть ошибку. Как я понимаю необходимо задать валидацию логина, но в библиотеке Hibernate и javax.validation я не обнаружил аннотации, которая может решить данную ситуацию. Подскажите, коллеги, есть ли библиотека которая поможет решить мою проблему, или необходимо задать собственную аннотацию, которая идёт в БД и проверяет есть ли пользователь с этим ключом?

Comment: структуру таблицы, включая ограничения, текст программы, где это происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как я понимаю необходимо задать валидацию логина, но в библиотеке Hibernate и javax.validation я не обнаружил аннотации, которая может решить данную ситуацию.

Естественно, что такой аннотации нет, ведь во всех приложениях различные таблицы, поля и логика для их проверки.

> Подскажите, коллеги, есть ли библиотека которая поможет решить мою проблему, или необходимо задать собственную аннотацию, которая идёт в БД и проверяет есть ли пользователь с этим ключом?

Да, все верно.

Вот пример, из моего проекта:

- [аннотация](https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/e2fb2fec835d5f0f1a1e662b1e9783bc0286f961/src/main/java/ru/mystamps/web/validation/jsr303/UniqueLogin.java)
- [реализация валидатора](https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/e2fb2fec835d5f0f1a1e662b1e9783bc0286f961/src/main/java/ru/mystamps/web/validation/jsr303/UniqueLoginValidator.java)
- [пример использования](https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/e2fb2fec835d5f0f1a1e662b1e9783bc0286f961/src/main/java/ru/mystamps/web/model/ActivateAccountForm.java#L70-L71)

Comment: Спасибо, ознакомился с вашей реализацией, но на мой проект не хочет правильно прикручиваться. Буду пробовать вводить свою реализацию.

Answer (score 0):

Да, надо проверить есть ли такой логин в БД.

```
select mytable where login=mynewlogin
```

Если вернет результат значит такой логин существует, поэтому мы его меняем.

Answer (score 0):

> Столкнулся с проблемой что при регистрации пользователя с существующим ключом - он перезаписывает всего- лишь старое значение, вместо того чтобы вернуть ошибку.

Похоже на то, что добавление в Hibernate реализовано через `currentSession().saveOrUpdate(...);` Как и указано в названии метода, Hibernate добавит сущность или обновит, если она существует. Если это так, поправьте название метода на `save(...)` - Hibernate будет возвращать SQL-ошибку первичного ключа, ее и обработаете.

Comment: использую spting data. работаю с моделями репозиторием. Метод сохранение saveAndFlush(user);